# Proper python config file styling?

Tags: python, config, styling, pep8

I know typical PEP8 standard is for comments as '# '. In the case of a config file where you have a mixture of comments and actual code that may need to be commented out, what is the convention? I've seen online where some suggest that Python config files should use '# ' for actual comments and '#' for commenting out actual code. That way, you distinguish between comments and potential code.

Example:

```
# Setting A does the following
#setting_a = 'true'

# Setting B does the following
#setting_b = 'true'
```

Does this make sense? Should you always use '# ' regardless of what the commented out 'content type' is? I know this is only a styling question, but I'm curious.

Comment: ideally, don't use python code for config at all. Use a config file format instead, like .ini, YAML, or JSON.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is one style commonly used for GNU/Linux config files, where in effect the author of the file has helped you out by providing examples of code you might like to add to the file. Not that those files are written in Python (at least most of them aren't: they're mostly shell scripts or non-executable text files) but at least the style will be familiar to those who've used such systems. Other such files put the space in both cases, it's not entirely consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter. Commenting out code should only ever be a temporary resort. If you really feel you might need that code back some time you should start using a version control system like `git` or `hg`, and delete unwanted code - you can always get it back from the earlier commits.

Comment: I'm referring to config files in large open source software projects. Whereby you may have a local, user settings file with a host of settings-options for them to uncomment if they so choose. Is there a convention for something like that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. Just explain whatever convention you adopt in comments at the head of the config file

Comment: thanks for the clarification, holdenweb